# Anyone know the name of this Star Wars brick

Tags: part-identification, piece-information, star-wars

[image: Star Wars piece]

Can someone help me find the name of this Star Wars piece and what set it came in?

Answer (score 9):

This is called [Windscreen 3 x 6 x 5 Bubble with Sith Infiltrator Pattern](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=30366px3#T=C):

[image]

It came only in the [7151-1: Sith Infiltrator](https://brickset.com/sets/7151-1/Sith-Infiltrator) set in 1999.